# A way to automatically reorder struct fields by their sizes in descending order

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++14, template-meta-programming, boost

Using `constexpr` and preprocessor magic it is possible to cook a struct which have a minimal size between all possible sizes, keeping all the data members properly aligned.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>

#include <utility>

#include <cstddef>

namespace details
{

template< std::size_t /*index*/, typename /*tag*/ >
struct member;

struct pair
{
    std::size_t k, v; 
    constexpr bool operator < (pair const & r) const { return r.k < k; }
};

constexpr void swap(pair & l, pair & r) { pair m = r; r = l; l = m; }

template< int N >
constexpr
void qsort(pair (&a)[N], int const l, int const r)
{ 
    int i = l, j = r;
    pair pivot = a[l + (r - l) / 2];
    while (!(j < i)) { 
        while (a[i] < pivot) ++i;
        while (pivot < a[j]) --j;
        if (!(j < i)) {
            swap(a[i], a[j]);
            ++i;
            --j;
        }
    }
    if (l < j) qsort(a, l, j);
    if (i < r) qsort(a, i, r);
}

template< int N >
struct map
{
    pair a[N];
};

template< int N, std::size_t ...indices >
constexpr
map< N > make_map(pair (&a)[N], std::index_sequence< indices... >)
{
    return {{a[indices]...}};
}

template< int N >
constexpr
map< N > qsort(pair (&&a)[N])
{
    if (1 < N) {
        qsort< N >(a, 0, N - 1);
    }
    return make_map< N >(a, std::make_index_sequence< N >{});
}

}

#define GEN0(z, tag, index, type_name) template<> struct member< index, tag > \
{ using type = BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(type_name); type BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(type_name)); };

#define GEN2(z, ignored, index, type_name) {sizeof(BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(type_name)), index},

#define GEN3(z, index, tag) details::member< tag::a.a[index].v, tag >

#define GEN(ns, tag, members) namespace details { \
namespace tags::ns { struct tag; } \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(GEN0, tags::ns::tag, members) \
namespace tags::ns { \
struct tag \
{ \
    static constexpr auto a = qsort({BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(GEN2, %%, members)}); \
}; \
} \
} \
namespace ns { \
using tag = struct : BOOST_PP_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(members), GEN3, details::tags::ns::tag) {};\
}

struct T { char c[3]; };

GEN(user::u2, S, ((char)(c))((int)(i))((T)(t)))

#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    using namespace details;
    void(member< 0, tags::user::u2::S >{}.c);
    void(member< 1, tags::user::u2::S >{}.i);
    static_assert(tags::user::u2::S::a.a[0].k == 4);
    static_assert(tags::user::u2::S::a.a[1].k == 3);
    static_assert(tags::user::u2::S::a.a[2].k == 1);
    user::u2::S s{4, {{'a', 'b', 'c'}}, 'd'};
    assert((void *)&s.i == (void *)&s);
    assert((void *)&s.t < (void *)&s.c);
    static_assert(sizeof(s) == 8);
}
```

[Live example (works for both *clang* and *gcc*).](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Fh5kOhyGhta3L58f)

Here is mapping of `sizeof` to indidces sorted by former, then type alias in desired namespace is created.

As you can see the code is dirty. Don't know what is optimal way to use `BOOST_PP_*` macro family and how to elaborate a better design (optional namespace, templated, allow to define `struct` not only in global namespace, etc (obvious things)).

Comment: What's your specific concern you want to see improvement for? Could you please elaborate that in your question?